# Advantage of Event Emitters over async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have been trying to understand the advantage of event emitters over async functions.

[image]

In the above example, I can understand that when 'play' is called, two functions get executed at the same time. My doubt is, that could be achieved by

```
await Promise.all(promises);
```

So does that mean event emitter is another way for parallel execution, with no real advantage over promises (except syntax wise)?

Also, does concurrent execution really happens, or is it happening serially? (refer to 'play' event in the above example)

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: I am not sure whether i got your point or not but generally I only use event emitters to pass value between components which do not have direct parent child relationship and I use promises when handling response from api's

Comment: I understand your explanation @VaibhavGattyani. But I am trying to understand why? Of course, we can't use emitters for api responses. Is there like a rule to use event emitters to be used for unrelated components? Why can't we go ahead with normal method calling?

Comment: No there is no rule, I use events between unrelated components because angular has "@input" and "@output" to share data between parent-child relation components.